# How to use VBA to add a certain number cells from the next row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way with VBA to add data from a lower row to the current row, and once a column limit is reached, start on the next line and keep going.  Start with something like this:

**Original...  5 Column**

[image: Original... 5 Column]

Then turn it into something like this:

**Ex.1...  7 Column**

[image: Ex.1... 7 Column]

Or this:

**Ex.2...  8 Column**

[image: Ex.2... 8 Column]

Comment: Seems you want to generate series of numbers Horizontal between 1 to 25, between col A and H,,,??

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is not by actually cutting & pasting data values from cell to cell, but slurping up the entire grid and then pasting it into the dimensions you want.

- Set your sub to take a range and a number (for the resulting column
  count).
- Loop through the range, adding each value to an array or
  other collection.
- Delete the existing data
- Go through the array inserting the values into the blanked sheet, until you hit the desired column count, then increment the row number and continue.